# Old processor(Sempron 3000+) won't boot anything with a 4.x kernel

Tags: boot, system-installation, kernel

On my old laptop,  Ubuntu 15.010, Ubuntu 16.04 and the latest Gparted and Clonezilla (all with a 4.x) Linux kernel won't boot, either from CD/DVD or via PXE.
If I try something with a 3.x kernel , it will boot from CD/DVD. Ubuntu 14.04 and Gparted 0.19.1.2 boot form CD/DVD and via PXE. Clonezilla 2.2.2-32 will boot from CD but fails under PXE  which is probably due to the parameters I have set in the cfg file. I'm sure that can be rectified eventually

In short anything with a 4.? kernel will fail and turn the machine off halfway through, producing no logs to go on. If it's an Ubuntu install it will trash the PC, so that only a reinstallation of 14.04 will fix it.

Is this something that I should expect and accept for an old machine with a newer kernel based install process, or is it a bug?

I feel that at the very least, it should fail in a tidier manner.

Comment: Are you using the 64-bit version?  I believe that CPU is a 32 bit.

Comment: No, all selections were 32 bit. If you were to try and install a 64 bit version on a a 32 bit machine, you would get a warning and a graceful exit

Comment: Hm.  I'm stumped then.  Perhaps this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the Sempron 3000+ supports PAE kernels and perhaps this is required for the later 32-bit kernels. You can find out if your CPU supports PAE with the command `cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep pae`

It seems that Ubuntu may have scrapped non-PAE kernels some time ago. I've been unable to find anything definitive, but there is an indication that this might be your problem [here.](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=60&t=117368)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it was a good one, however I believe that the cpu does support PAE. procinfo has: flags  : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca...........

Comment: Interesting. Which model based on which core?

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/85980/what-processors-do-do-not-support-pae